# What's the difference b/w (mask=mask) and (mask=mask_inverse) on OpenCV?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

Can someone point out the difference in working between them? I'm a newbie in OpenCV so there's e little confusion in the working between them.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img1 = cv2.imread('D:\Downloads_Chrome\python.png',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img2 = cv2.imread('D:\Downloads_Chrome\graph2.jpeg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
rows, cols, channel = img1.shape
roi = img2[0:rows, 0:cols]
img1_2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img1_2gray, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
img2_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask=mask_inv)
img1_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(img1,img1,mask=mask)
dest = cv2.add(img2_bg, img1_fg)
img2[0:rows, 0:cols] = dest
cv2.imshow('res',img2)
cv2.imshow('mask_inv',mask_inv)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('img2_bg',img2_bg)
cv2.imshow('img1_fg',img1_fg)
cv2.imshow('dest',dest)
cv2.imshow('img1_2gray',img1_2gray)
cv2.imshow('image1',img1)
#cv2.imshow('image2',img2)
if cv2.waitKey(0):
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How should we know if you don't include de definitions of `mask_inv` and `mask`? :)

Comment: I hope the edit solves the query. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `mask`, which is a binary image, is used to define/get the area you want in an image. Consider

```
I2=cv2.bitwise_and(I1,mask)
```

Since `mask` is binary, this is what will happen: everywhere `mask` is set to `0`, the image `I2` will be 0. However, everywhere `mask` is set to `1`, the image `I2` will retain the same content as `I1`.

Now, as @MH304 pointed out, `mask_inv` is just and image define like this (using `binary_not`):

```
mask_inv[i,j]=0  <=> mask[i,j]=1
mask_inv[i,j]=1  <=> mask[i,j]=0
#or equivalently, mask_inv[i,j]=1-mask[i,j]
```

So, doing

```
I3=cv2.bitwise_and(I1,mask_inv)
```

will mean that `I3` will retain everything that you discarded from `I1` to form `I2` previously. Similarly, `I3` will discard everything that you had used from `I1` to form `I2`. So in a sense, `I2` and `I3` are complements (*e.g.* forground/background).